# Python Three Letter Acronyms

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to check if a certain string contains an acronym using regex.

my current regex:

```
re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{3}', string)
```

currently it outputs true to `USA`, `NYCs`, and `NSFW` but it should not say true on `NSFW` because it is a four letter acronym, not three.

How can I readjust the regex to make it not accept `NSFW`, but still accept `NYCs`

EDIT: it should also accept `NYC,`

Comment: @thefourtheye This would exclude things like `NYCs` as 's' is a character

Comment: How about this `\b[A-Z]{3}[a-z]+`?

Comment: @thefourtheye wouldn't this require there to be a letter from a-z, and wouldnt that also disqualify things that have punctuation at the end, like `NYC,`

Comment: Please add all those rules in the question itself. Otherwise people have to guess answers.

Comment: Just edited it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> rexp = r'(?:\b)([A-Z]{3})(?:$|[^A-Z])'
>>> re.search(rexp, 'USA').groups()
('USA',)
>>> re.search(rexp, 'NSFW') is None
True
>>> re.search(rexp, 'aUSA') is None
True
>>> re.search(rexp, 'NSF,').groups()
('NSF',)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

A negative lookahead assertion: `(?!pattern)`

`re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])',string)`

This requires the triple capital pattern to never be followed by another capital letter, while it doesn't imply other restrictions, like the pattern necessarily be followed by something.
Think "Not followed by P" vs "Followed by not P"

Try:

```
filter(re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])').search, ['.ANS', 'ANSs', 'AANS', 'ANS.'])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the **?** to mean a character is optional, {0,1} would be equivalent.

You can put whatever characters you want to match inside the square brackets **[ ]** it will match any one of those 0 or 1 times so NYC. or WINs or FOO, will match.

Add the **$** to the end to specify no more characters after the match are allowed

```
re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{3}[s,.]?$', string)
```

Comment: For `NSFW` your regex will return `NSF`.

Comment: Yes. It also matched `USAA` and `NSFW`